# How to find a mongodb replicaset is created and the primary and all secondaries are set

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a mongodb replicaset with certain number of nodes. How to check programmatically, the replicaset is created with all the given nodes (1 primary and rest secondary) and ready for production use.

I am doing something like this. But I think there should be a better and efficient way of doing this.

Pseudo code:

```
replica_count=5
do:
  secondary_count = 0
  for node in mongdb_nodes:
    if `mongo --eval rs.isMaster().secondary` == "true":
      secondary_count++
while (secondary_count < replica_count-1)
```

Comment: You can use the [database#command](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=command#pymongo.database.Database.command) method - to this method pass the native command like, `replSetGetStatus` or `hello`.

Comment: Call `rs.status().members`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit still have to parse the ourput and findout the required number of nodes (secondaries) are up.

Comment: Why? When a node is not up, then the status will not be SECONDARY.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner would be this

```
rs.status().members.filter(x => !["PRIMARY", "SECONDARY"].includes(x.stateStr)).length == 0
```

However, it does not work if your Replica Set has an ARBITER node configured. In this case use

```
rs.status().members.filter(x => db.hello().hosts.includes(x.name)).filter(x => !["PRIMARY", "SECONDARY"].includes(x.stateStr)).length == 0
```

When the ARBITER is down then you can still write into the Replica Set.